# I want to keep my POST data using SESSIONS

Tags: php, html, session

After `submit` is selected on food.php and all the post data is gathered it is posted on homePage.php. 
How can I keep my `$_POST['meal']` from staying on the HomePage.php? 
Ive used `$_SESSION` in my code but for some reason it is not linking them together. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

food.php code:

```
<?php 


session_start();



if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $foodchoice = $_POST['meal'];


}




error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE );


if (isset($foodchoice)) 
{

$foodchoice = $_POST['meal'];

$_POST['meal'] = $_SESSION['meal'];

}

?>
```

homepage.php code:

This is to check if the sessions are working but they never do:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['meal'])) {

echo " foodchoice is set";

}

else if (!isset($_SESSION['meal'])) {

echo "nay!";

}
```

How I reference the `$_SESSION` data in homepage.php :

```
<?php  

if (is_array($_SESSION['meal']) || is_object($_SESSION['meal']))
{
    foreach ($_SESSION['meal'] as $checkbox)
    {
        echo "</br>  ".$checkbox . '';
    }


}

?>
```

Finally this is my form data:

```
<form action="homePage.php" method="post">

 <input type='checkbox' value='The Share Collection' name = "meal[]" id='button3'>

<input type='checkbox' value='Assorted Biscuits' name = "meal[]" id='button3'>

<input type='checkbox' value='Fruit Skewers' name = "meal[]" id='button3'>

<input type='checkbox' value='Bread Project' name = "meal[]" id='button3'>
 <input type='checkbox' value='Cheese Project' name = "meal[]" id='button3'>

<input type="submit" id="button4" value="Submit Your Selection" name="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

In foodchoice.php you are not assigning any value to $_SESSION['meal']. You have it backwards where it is:

```
$_POST['meal'] = $_SESSION['meal'];
```

change to 
`$_SESSION['meal'] = $_POST['meal'];` or `$_SESSION['meal'] = $foodchoice;`

Not sure why you are repeating $foodchoice = $_POST['meal']; inside of your second conditional unless I am missing something.

Comment: I have changed it to this but it still doesn't hold the values once I change to a different page

Comment: Make sure you have session_start() on each page where session data is going to be used.

Comment: I do still nothing is happening.

Comment: Not sure how your files are set up, but I just set up three. test.html with the form you provided, food.php for the processing, then test.php to dump the session data. Went from food.php to test.php with session data not being lost and displaying it with print_r($_SESSION);

Answer (score 0):

Your food.php should look like this:

```
<?php 

session_start();
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE );


if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $foodchoice = $_POST['meal'];

}

if (isset($foodchoice)) 
{
    $_SESSION['meal'] = $_POST['meal'];
}
```

Comment: This works great to post my data but I does not hold on to the data once I go to another page.

Comment: what do you see when you echo $_SESSION['meal'] on next page? because session data won't go away between pages unless you unset it manually.